# How can I allow power query in excel to fresh data one at a time automatically?

Tags: excel, vba, powerquery

Good day to everyone. You might think I am crazy and that is Ok. The problem is, if you can help me with my sanity.

I currently exact 67 tables, from one (1) web link (yes) that carries 67 tables and it update in power query in excel 67 times together.

Now. During this time my computer freezes about an hour because of the connections which are fleshing at the same time.

How can I allow excel to fresh data one at a time using VBA?

Would appreciate your feedback

Thanks in advance

Cheers

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1LyvwObe4hNsmZ13hJ9QUzLUaqxv43C5y/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Can you share the link?  Is there a way to download everything at once and import the downloaded dateset?  Just a couple of thoughts.